# How to report bulk upvotes?

Tags: discussion, upvotes

Lately I frequently see questions from a particular user, which are obviously connected to each other and a part of one project, which is pretty normal. I do take my time to answer, as I always do, when I can, and this apparently helps the user get going with the project. That's all OK.

The problem is, that when I last visited SO, my reputation has jumped with 125 rp. I am active on the Qt tag, where one post rearely recieves more than a couple of upvotes, if any, so such increase in the reputation is unusual for me. I suspect, the user has decided to thank me, because almost three years ago I've made the same mistake, trying to be grateful to the users here, who had helped me. I've learned that it is not a good thing and I may not do it. However, now I am on the other side of the line and I do not know what the appropriate action is.

I do not believe the user wanted to do any harm, exactly as my intentions were not bad, as I did the same. However, I should report this to be corrected. What is the way to do that?

Here is a list of the my posts I am speaking about:

[How to make QtLinguist shipped with Qt 5.9.1 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852340/how-to-make-qtlinguist-shipped-with-qt-5-9-1-work)

[QSlider increase handle size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47691972/qslider-increase-handle-size/47692691#47692691)

[Why does Q_OBJECT break QDoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52739030/why-does-q-object-break-qdoc)

[Why does Qt have to be built from source for cross-compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232525/why-does-qt-have-to-be-built-from-source-for-cross-compilation/52234279#52234279)

[How to use the activated route's data DIRECTLY in the HTML template containing the RouterOutlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447328/how-to-use-the-activated-routes-data-directly-in-the-html-template-containing-t/57447329#57447329)

[How to make QSerialPort from Qt5.13.1 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020663/how-to-make-qserialport-from-qt5-13-1-work)

[Does using C++ Lambda functions as slots in Qt help to preserve binary compatibility of a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871156/does-using-c-lambda-functions-as-slots-in-qt-help-to-preserve-binary-compatibi)

[QJsonObject ::insert compared to direct assignment to QJsonValueRef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664016/qjsonobject-insert-compared-to-direct-assignment-to-qjsonvalueref)

Comment: Please raise a custom moderator flag on one of their posts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, any specific content?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, should I list the bulk upvoted posts?

Comment: Any post will do; if there is a specific post that you suspect has been the focus then that’s probably helpful info to include, and if it makes this easier then put the flag on that specific post. It doesn’t really matter for us.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, there are 10 posts I susprect. I am raising the flag right now, including the links to the posts.

Comment: Thank you! We’ll take it from there. :-)

Comment: The flag does not let me write that much characters, so I listed the suspected posts in my question.

Comment: I'm surprised this behavior is seen as a bad thing.  I could see naturally browsing a user's profile that had answered several of my questions and subsequently browsing their other answered questions, and possibly +1ing a number of them.  This seems pedantic.

Comment: @java-addict301 using a user profile as a starting point to use your votes is a problem. Use a tag or other search and stumble on these posts naturally.

Comment: @java-addict301, many do not know this, incl. me at that time.

Comment: @scopchanov I guess what I'm saying is that I don't see the problem with the user's behavior.

Comment: @rene stumbling upon them naturally is good too, but I sometimes see multiple interesting posts when I browse someone's profile (especially if they have answered one of my questions, since many other questions may be related).  Am I supposed to ignore the curiosity to browse them?

Comment: @java-addict301, Here is an excerpt from the warning I received, when I was the one, who did it: _While we encourage everyone to upvote great posts, the motivation for doing so needs to be anchored in the merits of the post, not the person who wrote it._ After reading that it made more sense, although at first, exactly like you, I did not see anything wrong.

Comment: @java-addict301 yes, don't vote on posts where you used the user as method of finding these posts. it will get your votes reversed, it is confusing for the receiving user and worst case it gets you a warning if not a suspension. not worth it.

Comment: @scopchanov Yes I agree with the policy, however I don't think that the way one finds 'good' posts should matter, as long as the voting is being done on the merit of the post, and not the author..

Comment: @rene I guess I don't see it as confusing or a violation of the policy, if the voting is still done based on the merit of the question (without regard to the author).

Comment: @java-addict301 Think of it as rate-limiting - although *you* may have the best intentions, it does not mean everyone else does. Since no one's living is affected and the goal of SO is to build a knowledge repository, it is considered more beneficial to *prevent* voting fraud than let users *feel* good about upvoting/being upvoted. Note that there is nothing inherently wrong in serially upvoting a user (the less popular the tag, the more likely it is that a single group of users answer most of the questions), it is the irregularities that are harmful (like short bursts of "votes of affection")